# Could not compile service support class

Tags: livecode

I have been having this error since for Android compilation . 
My sdk url is oky, emulators are being detected but i cant generate any apk or run any android based app. Could

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite incomplete. Which LC version are you using, which Java JDK are you using, do you use Android Studio (just for the sdk) or do you have it installed via cdm? You need the Android sdk and Java Jdk.